# I have taken a joomla website offline, now I can't access either webmail,cpanel or administrator

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, webmail

I tried to take a Joomla website offline, so I made some changes in .htaccess. I tried this...

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

...but nothing happened at all.

Then I tried to turn the radio button (site offline) on in Joomla global settings and I put a message saying "the site is under maintenance".

Now the thing is, when users try to access the domain instead of showing my message it says the site is not available. It also happens when I try to access my webmail, cpanel, or administrator. It says "The server at domain.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed."

What happened?

There are some other users who need to reach their emails soon and it's a mess. I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Revert the changes in your .htaccess file (and wait a bit), you are essentially denying anyone from accessing the website. They can't access the offline page if they can't access the website.

Note that there are some hosts that delay the loading of the .htaccess file (no idea why) and cache the old version for an hour or so, that's why you probably haven't seen any changes to your website when you made the change to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Although if they are really getting the error "...DNS lookup failed", as stated, then this is more than just a `deny from ...` directive in .htaccess.